# SQL Pivot from multiple tables and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table, ssms-2014

I am working in SQL Server (SSMS) with three tables like so

Table A

```
ProcessID Step Approver  
  17       10    Kim  
  18       20    Joe  
  19       10    Beth  
  20       20    Josh
```

Table B

```
ProcessID DeptCode  
   17       515  
   18       515  
   19       190  
   20       190
```

Table C

```
ProcessID AlternateApprover  
   17        Sarah  
   18        David  
   19        Don  
   20        Don
```

and would like my results formatted as:

```
DeptCode FirstApprover FirstAlternate SecondApprover SecondAlternate  
   515       Kim           Sarah          Joe             David  
   190       Beth          Don            Josh            Don
```

I've managed a pivot on just the approvers successfully, but am not sure how to go about joining the alternates (Table C).

I understand that this normalization is a bit odd - it's not my database and I have no control over the table structure

Comment: What SQL do you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is easier way to pivot multiple columns.

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT  [DeptCode],
            [Approver],
            '' AS [Alternate],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DeptCode ORDER BY b.ProcessID) Rn
    FROM    TableB b
            JOIN TableA a ON a.ProcessID = b.ProcessID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  [DeptCode],
            '',
            AlternateApprover,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DeptCode ORDER BY b.ProcessID) Rn
    FROM    TableB b
            JOIN TableC a ON a.ProcessID = b.ProcessID
)
SELECT  [DeptCode],
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN [Approver] END) AS FirstApprover,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN [Alternate] END) AS FirstAlternate,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 2 THEN [Approver] END) AS SecondApprover,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 2 THEN [Alternate] END) AS SecondAlternate
FROM    cte
GROUP BY [DeptCode]
```

this assumes that First and Second order is determined by ProcessID `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DeptCode ORDER BY b.ProcessID)` since you have Step in TableA but not TableC I'm not sure what that field represents.

Comment: That worked just like I needed thanks! I am ordering by Step in TableA so I changed the one line to ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DeptCode ORDER BY a.Step) Rn in both and added a second JOIN TableA a ON a.ProcessID = b.ProcessID